# Translation of RNA into proteins

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, rna

**What's the least number of tRNA molecules needed to form a polypeptide chain that contain 50 amino acids of 15 types?**

> I know that each type of amino acid has at least one unique type of tRNA that recognizes it and transport it, so according to my understanding the 15 types of amino acids need at least 15 tRNA molecules of different types unless there was a reason that prevents one tRNA molecule from transporting two identical amino acids (two alanine) to the same polypeptide chain

•In other words:
*Can one tRNA molecule carry two identical amino acids (ex: two alanine) to the same polypeptide chain that's being synthesized or not?*

Comment: No, there is no way the same species of tRNA can carry two *different* amino acids no matter how similar they are. Each tRNA carries only one particular species of amino acid and there is no way it can just "switch to" any other one.

Comment: @YordanYordanov although physiologically I agree, and it answers the question, I just am wondering: there must undoubtedly be chemically modified amino acids variants that will be inserted into the growing peptide as well right?

Comment: I have to check this out but aren't the amino acids modified *after* they become inserted into the growing chain, not before. I will make a quick search online now. Here is one paper I managed to find with a very "quick" online search-https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3130931/ . As far as I can see all modifications are done *after* translation, not before. But there might be exceptions yet. I guess I would have to go deeper for this question.

Comment: @YordanYordanov — "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements Avoid answering questions in comments." You see these instructions when you click in a comment box. Please follow them or you are breaking the SE model.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "of the same type".

Comment: @David amino acid having the same code ex: two amino acid molecules with (GCG) code.

Comment: @David - it often happens that users do not feel confident writing up a full answer and comment. In my opinion, that is not breaking the model but making helpful comments to the user that won't do as a full blown answer. See *e.g.* [meta](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/552/comments-with-answers)

Comment: Jasmin, each codon (not code) specifies only one amino acid (in a given organism and subcellular compartment). GCG is the codon for alanine. If you think a codon can specify more than one amino acid (except in the special cases of selenocysteine) then you should study an elementary text on the genetic code.

Comment: @AliceD — I didn't make the rules, but I subscribed to them when I signed on. I also understand them. They are clearly explained on http://biology.stackexchange.com/tour. When the people who have set this site up feel so strongly about this rule that they put a reminder in the comment box, there is really no justification for flouting it. If one person does it others think it is permissible and one ends up with the sort of discussion forum and chit-chat that StackExchange expressly is not. If people are uncomfortable with the rules they should go somewhere else.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind would be an error in tRNA charging.

Comment: @David  Can't there be two amino acids of the same codon be found in one polypeptide chain of protein, as alanine to be present more than one time in the chain?!

Comment: Jasmin — Of course. But it was not obvious to me that this is what your question was about. Assuming that this is not a homework question  (is it?) you need to explain very clearly what your question is. 1. When you say "particular tRNA molecule" do you mean the same identical one molecule in the cell or molecules of the same class, i.e. with the same anticodon. 2. When you say "two similar amino acids" you need to make it clear that you are refering to two alanines or two glycines (I would use identical, rather than similar). Your question is still unclear, which is why it has close votes.

Comment: @David I hope that my question is clearer now. (Sorry for the inconvenience, but English is not my first language)

Comment: Jasmin — OK, but a strange question. And there are 20 different amino acids encoded in the standard genetic code, so I don't know why you picked 15, although a 50 amino acid protein could conceivably be lacking five amino acids. I suppose I have to answer your question now though.

Comment: Yes we can imagine that a tRNA can be recycled to incorporate the same amino acid into the same peptide chain multiple times so 16 tRNA could form a 50 amino acid chain but that will never happen thermodynamically. You need large concentrations of tRNA of all kinds for this reaction to take place, if you mix a single ribosome, mRNA and 15 tRNA with abundant free amino acids the reaction chemistry won't function.

Comment: @David - I know the rules and you are right. The thing is that it is a gray area. Personally, I indeed never give answers-disguised-as-comments, only when I expect the question to be closed and close-voting myself. Anyway, point taken.

Answer (score 2):

In the basic model of protein synthesis the events involving tRNA and amino acids are as follows (see any standard text, e.g. [Lodish *et al.* section 4.4](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21603/#A885)):

1. An amino acid is attached to the appropriate tRNA (the one with the anticodon that recognizes a codon for that amino acid) by one of twenty specific amino acyltRNA synthase enzymes in a reaction requiring ATP. This is called charging or aminoacylation of tRNA.
2. The tRNA corresponding to the mRNA codon is brought to the ribosome by an elongation factor (EF1) and the peptidyl transferase activity of the large ribosomal subunit catalyses the formation of a peptide bond between the growing polypeptide chain* and the amino acid of the tRNA, releasing deacylated tRNA.

I am unclear why you are concerned with this problem, but if there were two alanine codons in the mRNA, in theory after a particular discrete tRNA molecule had inserted the first alanine it could be recharged by the aminoacyl tRNA synthetase and then be used to insert the second alanine. However the concentration of tRNA molecules in the cell needed to support protein synthesis is such that the actual probability of this same discrete molecule being used, rather than another tRNA carrying alanine, is remote.

*A real-life complication is that a polypeptide chain has to be initiated by an initiator methionine-tRNA that is distinct from the methionine-tRNA that inserts internal methionines (see [Lewin *et al.* section 4.5](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21653/#A904)).